# If you have a DC in of 8.5V will a DC out of 19.5V work without ruining it?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

If you have a DC input of 8.5V will a DC output of 19.5V work without ruining it?

I have a PlayStation 2 that I don’t have a power cord for.

It says above the plug in on the console 8.5V.  I have an adapter with various tips you can put on it that has an output of 19.5V.

I was just going to try and see if it worked. But I’d rather not ruin it.

Will it ruin it if I try and use this?

Comment: Powering a 8.5V rated device with 19.5V is sure to kill it. In addition, if you do find a 8.5V adapter, make sure the polarity is correct as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: I have designed several consumer products that take power supplies. I have never tried to make one work correctly on double the normal voltage. Usually our attitude is that it is OK if the device is bricked as long as there is no fire or other dangerous failure. We tested up to 30V. So I think it is very doubtful that it will work, and there is a possibility that you will blow a fuse or cook a TVS or something that will prevent it from working in the future.

Comment: If you hate your Playstation, go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

**I would **not** recommend this**. Whenever you have device from a manufacture that states the required voltage (especially when you don't have a schematic to understand why that's the required voltage), it's best to stick with that voltage input so you don't risk damaging your system. If you did stick 19.5V into the system, best case scenario is that the system works just fine. Worst case is you start to see the magic smoke and it gets damaged.